# PYODBC pass variable in connection string

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to MS Access database (.mdb) with pyodbc. The following connection string works properly:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
                      r'DBQ=\\abc123.org\Team\Resources\Inputs\Accounts.mdb;')
```

I need to iterate over several files, so I'm trying to pass a variable in for the file path. Variables will come from a list but as an example:

```
file_path1 = '\\abc123.org\Team\Resources\Inputs\Accounts.mdb'

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ={};').format(file_path1)
```

I receive the following error:
Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid file name. (-1044) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid file name. (-1044)')

I receive the same error when trying:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%s;') % file_path1
```

Would appreciate any help on how to pass the file path as a variable in the connection string, thank you!

Comment: Is it only the `r the rawstring` missing before the file path `file_path1 = '\\abc123.org\Team\Resources\Inputs\Accounts.mdb'`?did you check?

Comment: I tried the following: file_path1 =  r'\\abc123.org\Team\Resources\Inputs\Accounts.mdb' and still receiving the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Paulo - I used your reply along with pathlib to resolve this issue:

```
import pathlib
file_path1 = pathlib.Path(r'\\abc123.org\Team\Resources\Inputs\Accounts.mdb')
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%s;' % file_path1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

```
file_path1 = '\\abc123.org\Team\Resources\Inputs\Accounts.mdb'

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ={};'.format(file_path1))
                                                                                  #^ format method is call on the string
```

Can you spot the difference ?

What you where doing was to call format on the `connect` method.
You have the same issue on the 2nd try too

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%s;' % file_path1)
                                                                                              #^ I have moved the parenthesis
```